# gem countries use Regexp

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, country

I use the country gem from hexorx, here is the link to gem
[Countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries)

I see in the code country.rb, that give Regexp as a parameter for searching country is possible. The Problem is, i even don't know how to use Regexp.
What i wanna do is, for example, give me all country that start with "T". I try with this

```
1.9.3-p327 :013 > c = Country.find_all_countries_by_name("/(T*)/")
 => []
```

how you can see, is doens't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

All countries that start with a T would look something like:

```
c = Country.find_all_countries_by_name("/^T[A-Za-z ]*/")
```

In this case you are doing the following:

```
/ - start of the match
^ - matches the start of the string (so the next character MUST be first)
T - literal T 
[A-Za-z ] - a "character class" allowing any a-z upper or lower plus space
* - repeat previous character (or character class) 0-many times
```

This is a great resource for learning regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/